# How do I move the column name up in my dataset?

Tags: r

I was attempting to clean up the dataset and realised str(data$datadate) did not work. Upon looking at the dataset, I realised the name of the columns were in row 1 and the column names were X1, X2, X3... How do I move up the first row (gvkey, datadate etc) to the column name instead?

[my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TazAi.png)

I have tried to change it manually by opening up the csv file but it showed no difference. Not quite sure how to rectify this issue.

Comment: Shouldn't you read in the file properly rather than fixing the mistake? Try `read.csv(..., header=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jay.sf suggested, you could fix the issue by re-reading your file correctly.

You can also use the `subset()` to create a new dataframe in which you use -c() annotation:

```
newDataFrame <- subset(oldDataFrame, -1, )
```

you could also use square brackets.

```
newDataFrame <- oldDataFrame[-1, ]
```

let's say if you wanted to drop the first and second rows, you'd use `-c(1,2)` instead of `-1`.